# detect sentence based on cursor

Tags: javascript, jquery, cursor, selection

```js
$("#paragraph").html("<span>The Faculty Development Programme would enable identification and preparation of relevant course transaction resources.</span><span> These resources include Reference Books, Films, PPTs, Case Lets and Case Studies Work Education, Experiential Learning and its various aspects, Village Project Work and Field Work and Preparation of Village Social and Resource Maps.</span>");


function detectSentence(){
   //console.log("Iam here");
   if (window.getSelection && (sel = window.getSelection()).modify) {
       selection = window.getSelection();
       selection.extend (selection.focusNode.parentNode, 0);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div contenteditable="true" id="paragraph">
</div>
<br><br>
<button type="button" onclick="detectSentence()" id="btn">
Detect Sentence
</button>
```

I have a div which contains a paragraph, this paragraph can have more than 1 sentence. I am enclosing these sentences in a span tag, so that each sentence is separated. So sentence boundaries are already identified in the text. Now when the focus is anywhere in this div, is there a way to detect the sentence where the cursor belongs to.

I had tried using `window.getSelection();`, but couldn't attain a solution of how to use this method. My question is there a way to move the selection to the nearest opening and closing `span` tag surrounding the cursor so that the corresponding sentence will be highlighted where the cursor is present.

Using this snippet I am able to select text up to starting sentence tag but the ending sentence tag is not being highlighted. To test the snippet click anywhere in the div and click on the button Detect Sentence.

Comment: See this fiddle which was linked to in the duplicate I marked: http://jsfiddle.net/vv9gD/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code gives you the element cursor is on or element with selected content.

```js
$("#paragraph").html("<span>The Faculty Development Programme would enable identification and preparation of relevant course transaction resources.</span><span> These resources include Reference Books, Films, PPTs, Case Lets and Case Studies Work Education, Experiential Learning and its various aspects, Village Project Work and Field Work and Preparation of Village Social and Resource Maps.</span>");

detectSentence = function(){
   var node = document.getSelection().anchorNode;
   sentenceElem = node.nodeType == 3 ? node.parentNode : node;
   console.log(sentenceElem)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div contenteditable="true" id="paragraph">
</div>
<br><br>
<button type="button" onclick="detectSentence()" id="btn">
Detect Sentence
</button>
```